# Binary Numbers Larger than Accumulator size to Decimal Characters

Tags: binary, decimal, microcontroller

How binary numbers bigger than the size of accumulator are converted to human readable decimal characters. For example, I have an 8-bit microcontroller and I need to display a 16-bit number in decimal form on an LCD display. Repeated division is not possible since the number is greater than accumulator size. It will be very helpful to get a general algorithm (and links) for that purpose.

Comment: it will be good if you post what all coding you tried

Comment: What's the type of MCU are you using? What's the programming language are you using? ... What's the dimension of the number you have to display?

Comment: Isn't that type of algorithm given in the manufacturer's handbook or data sheet, seeing as they usually provide basic algorithms to make their product easily usable? I think you need to do a bit of research yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning accumulators can only mean you're looking for an assembly language solution.  But, you haven't mentioned the specific assembly language, so I'm giving you general guidance.

There are several ways you can solve this problem but the one below is the most general solution that can be extended to any byte size number.

You need some division operation that will take, at a minimum, a 16-bit dividend and an 8-bit divisor.  If your hardware does not provide one you can always write a software equivalent using the old shift-and-subtract method.

The steps to convert binary to its decimal ASCII representation are these:

1. Start with a remainder of zero.  (In every step your divisor is always 10 because this is your target number base.)
2. Concatenate the current remainder (zero initially) with the next byte (from MSB to LSB) of the 'long' number you want to convert.  This 16-bit value is your current dividend.
3. Divide the 16-bit dividend of step 2 with 10.  Save the quotient over the original number.
4. Bump up the pointer to the next byte and loop back to step 2 until all bytes have been divided.
5. The final remainder is your right-most result digit.  (The result will be formed from right to left, so you will need to reverse the order at the end.  Keeping each result digit in the stack makes this quite simple.)
6. Add the value of ASCII character '0' to the final remainder to convert it to ASCII.
7. Save the ASCII digit (preferably on the stack to make reversal simpler).
8. Loop back to step 1 until your original number becomes zero.

If using the stack to save the result, make sure you first push a zero on it to act as a flag when to stop pulling/popping the result from it.

*For 16-bit numbers, an alternate 'primitive' method is to repeatedly subtract 10000, 1000, 100, 10 from the number until the number is too small for yet another subtraction, while keeping track of the number of subtractions for each number.  These counters will form the decimal equivalent which you will then need to convert to ASCII by adding '0' on each digit.  This method does not scale well as the number byte size increases.*

Hope this helps.